# Swift UICollectionView Cells Mysteriously Repeat

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, collectionview

We are trying to make a collection view. In each cell the users can choose an image and enter text into a text field. We noticed that after adding four cells, when we add a new cell, the text field is already filled with the information from previous cells. In our code, we never programmatically fill the text field (which starts out empty), we allow the user to do this. Any suggestions?

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Image", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.deleteButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddNewItem.xButtonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.deleteButton?.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "index")
    let item = items[indexPath.item]
    let path = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(item.image)
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3).CGColor
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 7

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you are using `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier` which returns already created cell(that you were using before). That's why it's already filled with previous data. You need to clear this data before showing this cell, or fill it from some storage(for example array that represents your collection view cells(each object in array somehow related to cell, in your case that is text wroten in cell))

Comment: Do you know why the data repeats after 4 cells? So, the 4th cell will contain the same data as the first cell, the fifth the same data as the 2nd cell and so on.

Comment: Yes, because you screen size can view in one time 4 cells, that's why it appears after 4 cells.

Comment: I can help you solve this problem tomorrow or describe it deeply, if you need it.

Comment: I just figured it out!  Thanks!

Comment: @OliviaWatkins how did you resolve it?  I am having probably similar issue.

Comment: @DarylWong I just posted an answer explaining how I resolved it.  Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this in UICollectionViewCell custom class

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.profileImg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Profile Icon Empty")

    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```

Comment: Which is exactly what this method is for. :)

Comment: @Abizern prepareForReuse from Apple Doc:

if the cell is reusable (has a reuse identifier), this is called just before the cell is returned from the table view method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:.  If you override, you MUST call super.

Comment: @GentBerani I know. I was confirming that this is the method that should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ultimately ended up resolving it.

I created an `Item` class which contained all of the fields which are shown in the collection view cell and created an array of Items.

Here is a simplified version of my `CollectionViewCell` class, which here only has a single text field:

```swift
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemName: UITextField!

    var item: Item?

    func initializeListeners(){
        itemName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(itemNameChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    }


    //When the item name is changed, make sure the item's info is updated
    func itemNameChanged(textField: UITextField) {
        item?.itemName = textField.text!
    }
}
```

Here's a simplified version of the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function in my view controller class:

```swift
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.initializeListeners()
    let item = items[indexPath.item]
    cell.item = item
    cell.itemName.text = item.itemName
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that **collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height**

is taller than the real contents size! It is recommended to keep UICollectionView calculate the height automatically (without using UIScrollView, let UICollectionView maintain the scroll), as manual change will cause lots of weird behaviors.